# socket.io connect to specific endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am testing socket.io, converting from javascript default socket communication.

My current code connects like this:

```
wsuri = "wss://" + window.location.hostname + ":9000";
sock = new WebSocket(wsuri);
```

How can I connect to this same websocket with socket.io?

I have tried:

```
var sock = io.connect('https://website.com',{secure: true, port:9000});
```

and in the console I see:

```
https://website.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LCU64Ep   404: not found
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since socket.io uses HTTP as the first transport, and upgrades to web sockets after connecting with the web server you need to run socket.io together with a HTTP server like Node http server, Express or something similar and run socket.io together with that.

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
```